# How to create file based on database data in python?

Tags: python

I have a table called '**CompanyData**' that contains data of various companies. I need to store the data in a file corresponding to each company name.

The columns are

```
c_emp_id, name, ph, email, company_name, country
```

How can I able solve the problem using Python

My try:

```
import os
import pymysql

user = '***'
password = '***'
host =  '***'
db= '***'

connection = pymysql.connect(host, user, password, db)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "select * from CompanyData"
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
for value in results:
    filename = "{}.txt".format(value[4])
    if os.path.isfile(filename )
        fh = open(filename, 'w')
    string1 = "{}-{}-{}\n".format(value[1], value[2], value[3])
    if 'fh' in locals():
        fh.write(string1)
```

I am simplifying my problem here so that one can understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `pandas`. The key is to group your data by company name and then to save each group to a different file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'company': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA']}) # Example of data

#       company name
# 0     AAA    A
# 1     BBB    B
# 2     AAA    C

groups = df.groupby('company')
for company, group in groups:
    group.to_csv('{0}.txt'.format(company), sep='-')
```

In this example, two files will be created: `AAA.txt` and `BBB.txt`. The content of these files will be:

```
-company-name
0-AAA-A
2-AAA-C
```

and

```
-company-name
1-BBB-B
```

In order to convert your mysql database to a pandas DataFrame, you can do the following:

```
import mysql.connector as sql
import pandas as pd

db_connection = sql.connect(host='hostname', database='db_name', user='username', password='password')
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table_name', con=db_connection)
```

Comment: I have not used the pandas module. SO can you please tell me how can I able to put/convert my data __results__  to  __pandas data frame__.

Comment: @Arijit See my new answer (that should work but I haven't tested it)

Comment: In the output file, I am getting all comma separated columns. But I need to format the output. like  __string1 = "{}-{}-{}\n".format(value[1], value[2], value[3]))__. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: @Arijit you can choose any separator that you want with the `sep` optional keyword: `group.to_csv('{0}.txt'.format(company), sep='-')`

Comment: Thank's @Julien.  Is there any way to skip few fields. for example, I am printing only first three fields.

Comment: @Arijit There are many many things that you can do with each group dataframe (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html). To only print the 3 first columns, you can use `group[group.columns[:3]].to_csv('{0}.txt'.format(company), sep='-')`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if "group by" can help, but i can try to help out with code.

first collect all the data for a company in a dict and then perform the write, also try to use the "with" statement for "open", this will handle the closing of the file.

```
import os
import pymysql

user = '***'
password = '***'
host =  '***'
db= '***'

connection = pymysql.connect(host, user, password, db)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "select * from CompanyData"
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
company_data = {}

# collect data into a dict
for value in results:
    company = value[4]
    try:
        current_data = company_data[company]
        current_data += "\n" + "-".join([value[1], value[2], value[3]])
        company_data[company] = current_data
    except KeyError:
        current_data = "-".join([value[1], value[2], value[3]])

# write the data into the file
for company, data in company_data.iteritems():
    filename = "%s.txt" % company
    with open(filename, 'w') as fh:
        fh.write(data)
```

saving into the dict might create a lot of intermediate strings (current_data += "\n" + "-".join([value[1], value[2], value[3]])); not sure if the below using lists is a better implementation.

```
# collect data into a dict
for value in results:
    company = value[4]
    try:
        current_data = company_data[company]
        # since lists are mutable we do not need to re-assign this back to dict
        current_data.append("-".join([value[1], value[2], value[3]])
    except KeyError:
        current_data = "-".join([value[1], value[2], value[3]])

# write the data into the file
for company, data in company_data.iteritems():
    filename = "%s.txt" % company
    with open(filename, 'w') as fh:
        for line in data:
            fh.write(line + "\n")
```